# Button wont click in html/ javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get this button in html to create a new string, but it doesnt do anything..

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Random Quote Generator</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
     <script src="Reffference.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <h1>Random Quote Generator</h1>
            <div class="message">Click the button to generate a quote!</div>
        <button id="getMessage" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me!</button>    

        </div>

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript in the file Reffference.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#getMessage").on("click", function(){


    $(".message").html("Here is the new generated text");
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks every thing is fine in your code.Make sure your jquery load in your web page properly.

Comment: Hey- Your code is fine please make sure your js files is loaded completly and cookies is cleared

Comment: Since everybody agrees that your code is working, there is nothing we can do to help you get it work without more information. You need to do some debugging on your own, especially make yourself familiar with your browser's developer tools and look for any errors you might get.

Comment: [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b9epyauv/1/) is your code, all the external libraries are exactly what you've loaded - works like it should - check that `Reffference.js` is loaded (use the developer tools to verify that)

Comment: sprinkle some console.log messages in your javascript, see which ones are output to the console and which ones are not

Comment: try the JS in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b9epyauv/2/) for your `Reffference.js` - you should see three messages in the console when the page is loading and one for a click

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is working fine perfectly. If there is any issues in your local, please check the console and see whether any error is logged.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It is not working for me for some reason? I am using brackets to edit my code

Comment: If you are using the brackets editor, please verify there is no code syntax issues, Some times brackets while beautifying the code will violates some basic html, javascript syntax.

Answer (score -3):

Given that you code works fine in jsfiddle etc the only possible thing could be the reference.js file. Please ensure its in the same directory as the html (because thats where your link is looking for it) and check your case e.g. call the file reference.js not Reference.js in both the link and filename.

Also check your spelling, in your HTML you have it spelt Reffference.js (3 fs).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#getMessage").on("click", function() {
    $(".message").html("Here is the new generated text");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <h1>Random Quote Generator</h1>
            <div class="message">Click the button to generate a quote!</div>
        <button id="getMessage" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me!</button>    

        </div>

    </div>
    </body>
```

---

Can you try just using this HTML and see if it works. Note: I have included the js at the bottom rather than externally. This will rule out the file not being loaded:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Random Quote Generator</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
     <!-- <script src="Reffference.js"></script> -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <h1>Random Quote Generator</h1>
            <div class="message">Click the button to generate a quote!</div>
        <button id="getMessage" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me!</button>    

        </div>

    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#getMessage").on("click", function(){
            $(".message").html("Here is the new generated text");
            });
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If this worked then it confirm the issue is `<script src="Reffference.js"></script>`

So your link should look like this:

`<script src="reference.js"></script>`

and its important that it comes after the link to jquery (which you have, but just saying :)

Its really important that your reference.js file is name exactly that. no caps.

the contents of the reference.js file should be:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#getMessage").on("click", function(){
        $(".message").html("Here is the new generated text");
        });
    });
```

Your project directory should look like this:

```
MyProject ->
    index.html
    referenece.js
```

Comment: If there is no problem then there is no need to answer.

Comment: if theres no problem then there was no need to ask either. im merely letting OP know that the code he posted works fine and is not his problem. this in itself is somewhat an answer.

Comment: You can do that in a comment too. *"if theres no problem then there was no need to ask either."* Right, that's why the question should be closed, not answered. If there is indeed a problem the OP needs to clarify. Posting an answer saying everything is fine is not useful to anybody.

Comment: yet the OP obviously has some issue or they wouldn't be asking. narrowing it down means he can figure out the right question to ask. why don't you provide some answers, guidance rather than just criticising everyone else's answers.

Comment: I provide guidance: You should vote to close the question instead of answering it.

Comment: And how would that help the OP?

Comment: How does it help the OP to write an *answer* that just says "works fine"? Does it help them solve their problem? Not at all. How are you helping them to narrow the problem down?

Comment: i am receiving this error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: As you surely know, debugging is often times a case of ruling things out, the OP obviously believes the error lies in the does he has posted. but us confirming that there is nothing wrong with the code, he can begin to look at other sources for the bug. I don't understand how someone of your rep cant see this.

Comment: @Christian Which file is it saying it failed to load? the jquery file?

Comment: *"but us confirming that there is nothing wrong with the code,"* Why does that require an *answer*? That should be done in a comment. Then the OP can investigate, update their question and you can provide an actual answer.

Comment: Try using the layest jquery cdn ( https://code.jquery.com/ ). I appreciate you may have a requirement to use a specific version but it will atleast confirm if its the jquery file your linking thats causing the problem.

Comment: Because Felix, I cannot post a working example in a comment, now please either contribute or go away

Comment: Brad, if your position is that there must be a problem in something not shown then why didn't you actually say that in your answer? It still wouldn't actually answer the question, but it would at least be more meaningful than just saying that the existing code works.

Comment: it fails to load this http://127.0.0.1:64442/favicon.ico. Sorry guys, I am super new to programming and I have no idea why it is isn't loading in Brackets, it works in codepen and jsfiddle, but not brackets

Comment: Dont worry about the favicon, thats just an icon its nothing to worry about regarding this issue. Can you confirm what you mean by not working in brackets?

Comment: @nnnnnn Its implied surely.

Comment: *"I don't understand how someone of your rep cant see this"* Maybe you should take this as indication that I have some experience with this site and have a good idea of what makes a proper answer. But I don't want to argue with you, I've said my part. You can take my advice or not.

Comment: Ok, comments taken onboard, now please, let me continue trying to help the OP. Thank you for your huge contribution.

Comment: @brad I am using the code editor "Brackets", when i click live preview, everything loads up, but when I try to click the button, nothing happens

Comment: @Christian is your file reference.js in the same directory as the html page? also i would recommend keeping it lowercase in both the filename and the link.

Comment: Is the contents on the page centered with a blue Click me! button - or is it left aligned with a standard Click me! button?

Comment: They are in the same directory @brad

Comment: @Christian check the spelling. Reffference.js with 3 fs

Comment: at least that shows your external resources are loading fine :p

Comment: @brad still no luck

Comment: @christian please see second part of my answer, please can you try replacing your html with that and see if it works.

Comment: @ so the issue is the way you are linking your reference.js Ill add a bit more to the answer. sec

Comment: @Christian ok see latest edit to answer. please confirm you have all that.